# Does this generate a memory leak?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
void aFunction_2()
{
    char* c = new char[10];
    c = "abcefgh";
}
```

Questions:

1. Will the: `c = "abdefgh"` be stored in the `new char[10]`?
2. If the `c = "abcdefgh"` is another memory area should I dealloc it?
3. If I wanted to save info into the `char[10]` would I use a function like `strcpy` to put the info into the `char[10]`?

Comment: @GMan: <smacks_head> Well, it is indeed C++ then. But C-ish C++. Thus bad C++. I'm with Zan on this. Use `std::string`.

Comment: @sbi: It's all good. :) I agree: separate resource management from resource usage.

Answer (score 8):

Yes that is a memory leak.

Yes, you would use strcpy to put a string into an allocated char array.

Since this is C++ code you would do neither one though. You would use std::string.

Answer (score 6):

```
void aFunction_2()
{
    char* c = new char[10]; //OK
    c = "abcefgh";          //Error, use strcpy or preferably use std::string
}
```

> 1- Will the: c = "abdefgh" be
>   allocated inner the new char[10]?

no, you are changing the pointer from previously pointing to a memory location of 10 bytes to point to the new constant string causing a memory leak of ten bytes.

> 2- If the c = "abcdefgh" is another
>   memory area should I dealloc it?

no, it hasn't been allocated on heap, its in read-only memory

> 3- If I wanted to save info inner the
>   char[10] I would use a function like
>   strcpy to put the info inner the
>   char[10]?

not sure what you mean with 'inner' here. when you allocate using new the memory is allocated in the heap and in normal circumstances can be accessed from any part of your program if you provide the pointer to the memory block.

Answer (score 0):

1. No (pointer reassignment)
2. No
3. Yes, you can use `strcpy()`, see [for instance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/):

Comment: In first case, the pointer changes and doesn't point to allocated memory anymore. so 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer already has been answered multiple times, but I think all answers are missing one important bit (that you did not ask for excplicitly):
While you allocated memory for ten characters and then overwrote the only pointer you have referencing this area of memory, you are created a memory leak that you can not fix anymore. To do it right, you would std::strcpy() the memory from the pre-allocated, pre-initialized constant part of the memory where the content of your string-literal has been stored into your dynamically allocated 10 characters.

And here comes the important part:

When you are done with dealing with these 10 characters, **you deallocate them using `delete[]`**. The `[]` are important here. Everything that you allocate using `new x[]` has to be deallocated with `delete[]`. Neither the compiler nor the runtime warn you when use a normal `delete` instead, so it's important to memorize this rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, that is only pointer reassignment;
2. No, `delete`ing something that didn't come from `new` will often crash; and
3. Yes, `strcpy` will do the job… but it's not usually used in C++.

Since nobody has answered with code, `std::uninitialized_copy_n` (or just `std::copy_n`, it really doesn't make a difference here) is more C++ than `strcpy`:

```
#include <memory>

static char const abcs[] = "abcdefgh"; // define string (static in local scope)
char *c = new char[10]; // allocate
std::copy_n( abcs, sizeof abcs, c ); // initialize (no need for strlen)

// when you're done with c:
delete[] c; // don't forget []
```

Of course, `std::string` is what you should use instead:

```
#include <string>
std::string c( "abcdefgh" ); // does allocate and copy for you
// no need for delete when finished, that is automatic too!
```